# Franklin Gothic Medium shows up as Times New Roman on Apple PCs

Tags: css, font-face

I have a site and the CSS script sets the font by:

`font-family:"Franklin Gothic Medium";`

But on my friends MAC laptop (two tries now) it shows up as Times New Roman... Any idea how I can fix this or do I need a new font? I thought Franklin Gothic was a pretty basic font...

Comment: This is already answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6498866/362536  Not everyone has your fonts.  If you have a font that you **must use**, then you need to use a web version of it and embed it.  Even then, it may render differently.  Specify fallback font families, eventually going back to serif or sans-serif.

Comment: Both your and your friend's computers are doing it wrong: on my Linux box, it shows as Liberation ;).

Comment: Your friend probably doesn't have the fon on his mac. I don't have it on the one I use at work. Try using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator to embed your fonts on your website.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good tutorial on how to include the font file with your website so that other computers that don't have the font can grab it straight from your server:
http://www.miltonbayer.com/font-face/

I would also seriously suggest looking into [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) which does all of the work for you.