# Google fonts in windows is jagged

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I've seen a lot of posts on this, but people have written that it's only rendering improperly in windows Chrome. In my case, it's most of the browsers including the IE's. Cleartype is turned on by default, so that was not the issue.

I can't believe that windows can't handle Google Fonts properly. Perhaps, someone out there might have a workable solution or a reasonable fallback.

Is it wise to just use Arial for Windows machines? Is there a script that detects OS type, and if so, should I implement it? I know I should just choose a basic font, but I might as well please the OSX crowd?

EDIT:

I should add that I'm using News Cycle. It even looks kind of bad on the Google Fonts website at 18px and below.

Comment: Yes, because what OS your users use determines the font they find readable...

Comment: I had this problem before. I had to change font-weight for windows v 6 and up altogether... Google fonts that I used became too thin...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font Rendering differently when using MAC vs PC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498855/font-rendering-differently-when-using-mac-vs-pc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose your fonts wisely and always test. Google fonts is an amazing resource but not every font will display correctly or even be legible across all browsers/platforms.

Edit:
There lots of resources on google on fonts. You need to research 'font stacks' and that will shed some light on your choice of fallback fonts. IMHO, I don't really think user agent sniffing is necessary in this case ...

Here is a pretty good article, although a bit old:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/22/complete-guide-to-css-font-stacks/

Comment: That is the web dev way - the hard way ;)

Comment: Thanks I will read that article, but don't font stacks just use the next best font if the first one doesn't exist? In this case, the news cycle font exists, but it just looks bad.

Comment: That's correct. But a good font stack will fall to a font that has measurements close to yours (like x-height) , looks legible on that platform and isn't comic sans, which is always a bonus. From my experience, plenty of google web fonts aren't really that good for body text ... usually they are too thin or there are problems with rendering !

Comment: Is it normal to use custom fonts for headings and leave the body with system fonts?

Comment: Most of the system fonts are well, quite boring, so there was always some effort to push custom fonts and stand out (headings in images ughh...). Then again, look at SO's font stack - first font, Arial. I would say system fonts are very common for body text, especially on big sites.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the jagged-rendering issue, but for fallback, you can detect the OS using the `navigator.userAgent` property in JavaScript.

Windows user-agents contain the substring `NT x.y`, for instance `NT 6.1` is for Windows 7.

**Edit:** You can also use the `navigator.appVersion` property. Here's a sample:

```
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1)
    OS = "Windows";
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1)
    OS = "MacOS";
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11") != -1)
    OS = "Unix";
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux") != -1)
    OS = "Linux";

if(OS == "Windows") {
    //add specific styles
}
```

To automate the process, you can use [CSS User Agent](http://cssuseragent.org/), which adds classes to elements depending on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

I've only had the problem in Chrome on Windows. A workaround used to be to add an invisible text-shadow or rotate the text just a tiny bit, but that has stopped working since about version 16. I've found that sometimes the following CSS property can help with some fonts:

```
-webkit-text-stroke-width: .5px;
```